# How can I prevent my texas toast from sticking together?

Tags: freezing

It's a real problem. Can't cook em stuck together.

Comment: Can you clarify? Sticking together... in the freezer, maybe?

Comment: You mean the slices? I don't generally have issues separating slices of frozen bread... Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: They're coated in a seasoning which causes the sticking. Sometimes you can get a knife between the slices to split, but not always.

Comment: If it's a packed frozen item from the store ... this could be a sign that it's thawed and then refrozen.  This could be a sign of bad handling at the store, but it could also happen if you buy it on hot days and you have to trave a bit to get it home.  I suggest investing in a freezer bag, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making it yourself... freeze the slices separately before putting them in a container. Put them in a single layer on a baking sheet, then put the sheet in the freezer. When frozen, seal them tightly in a bag or wrap in plastic wrap. Since they're already frozen, they won't stick together.

(They do similar things commercially with shrimp, fruits, and other things. It's called Individual Quick Freezing.)

If you're having a problem with store-bought bread, you're kinda stuck. You can try defrosting it in the microwave to make it easier to separate the slices. But really, they should have been IQF frozen or otherwise prepared. They may have defrosted and re-frozen, which is a sign of improper handling (either at the store or by you).

Comment: You can also arrange the bread in such a way that each piece is separated from another with baking paper. Though I'm not sure how well this would work if both sides are sticky..